# LARAVEL MAIL: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: laravel, email, swiftmailer

I can send email in my localhost, but when I put it in our remote server I get this error:

[image]

I don't know what the problem is. Anyone?

I used the laravel default mail driver which is swiftmailer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702362/laravel-expecting-response-250-but-got-with-message?rq=1 ?

Comment: @SpliFF. I don't use sendgrid. I use the default mail driver in laravel which is swiftmailer. anyway, similar error, but different mail driver.

Comment: You might also want to check possible causes listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570480/smtp-code-250-but-email-lost-at-remote-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Expecting response 250 but got "" with message ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702362/laravel-expecting-response-250-but-got-with-message)

Answer (score 0):

Check your gmail: in settings, enable access for less secure apps and it will work.